# ViewMatrix calculation messes up models

Tags: javascript, matrix, webgl, transformation

I have a WebGL application which renders an array of cubes, each with a different height. To size them I use the transformation matrix to scale the cubes. I also have a camera, which can be moved with the keyboard.

To calculate the model matrix I use the following code:

```
let matrix = matrix4Identity();
matrix = matrix4Translate(matrix, this.position);
matrix = matrix4Rotate(matrix, this.rotation[0], [1, 0, 0]);
matrix = matrix4Rotate(matrix, this.rotation[1], [0, 1, 0]);
matrix = matrix4Rotate(matrix, this.rotation[2], [0, 0, 1]);
matrix = matrix4ScaleWithVector(matrix, this.scale);
```

and to calculate the view matrix I use this code:

```
let matrix = matrix4Identity();
matrix = matrix4Rotate(matrix, camera.rotation[0], [1, 0, 0]);
matrix = matrix4Translate(matrix, [camera.position[0], camera.position[1], camera.position[2]]);
return matrix4Inverse(matrix);
```

and this is the vertex shader code I use:

```
attribute vec3 vertices;
attribute vec3 normals;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

void main(void) {
    vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(vertices, 1.0);
    vec4 modelPosition = viewMatrix * worldPosition;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelPosition;
}
```

However, if you move the camera, the cubes get translated. So when you move the camera upwards, the (visual) Y-position of the cubes change. Furthermore, if you rotate the camera, it actually rotates the cubes around their X-Axis. 
However, if I remove the scale transformation in the model matrix, the blocks don't change their position anymore on moving the camera.

You can see the project result here. https://renuo.github.io/stayOFline/
Use WASD to move in the X and Z axes, R to move up and F to move down and o+l to rotate the camera.

**Update:**

When first translating and the rotating the camera, I get the following behaviour:

[image: rotating camera]

You can view the whole code under https://github.com/renuo/stayOFline/tree/gh-pages

Comment: you sure you want to rotate the camera first instead of translate it first? Rotating first will move the camera around the origin at camera position out. Translating first will put the camera at that position and then rotate at that position

Comment: I agree with first translating and then rotation. However, it doesn't solve my problem. The weird drift in the Y-Axis of the blocks on moving the camera in the y direction is still there. Furthermore, the blocks then just rotate around the position of the camera, but in a weird way and not in the expected way…

Comment: I updated my question with the view matrix calculation change

Comment: Maybe you need to post a working snippet. In particular we need to see your matri functions since it appears your not using a common library.

Comment: The matrix functions are available here: https://github.com/renuo/stayOFline/blob/master/engine/Math.js (as well as the rest of the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters in the function call:
https://github.com/renuo/stayOFline/blob/100a890c177d5cacc2e98fd5df196740899abf38/engine/Renderer.js#L37
need to be switched.

```
program.updateUniforms(this, camera, model, light)
```

should be:

```
program.updateUniforms(this, model, camera, light)
```